# How do I get two floating images next to each other to align with the images above and below?

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have mostly single images on my portfolio pages, but I'd like to incrorporate two images/videos next to each half-way down. You can see that here: https://kaye.hu/ett/islovingherself

The images are set to 10px padding all round, which of course messes with the padding when floating two 50% images next to each other. I've tried amending to a lower size (48%) but it still doesn't line up and I just can't get my head around how to do it!

So, the HTML is..

```
<img class="one img-responsive" />
<img class="one img-responsive" /> 
<img class="one img-responsive" />
...

<img class="two img-responsive" />
<img class="two img-responsive" />
```

And CSS:

```
.img-responsive {
padding: 10px;
float: left;
}

img.one {
max-width: 100%;
}

img.two {
max-width: 48%;
}
```

I just can't get my head around the best way to it.

Comment: look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing , to set your padding and 50% together ;)

Comment: Ugh, that is genius! Thankyou!